# Return array from Node.js function

Tags: node.js

I'd like to read some information from an remote CSV file using a callback function. Not sure, how exactly to do this.

**function:**

```
function getRoomsFromCSV(allRoomsArray) {
  var request = require('request');
  request('http://localhost:3333/rooms.csv', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
...
      allRoomsText = allRoomsText.substr(0,allRoomsText.length-1) + ']}';
      var allRoomsArray = JSON.parse(allRoomsText);
  }
 })
}
```

I'd like to call the function and loop through the result array.

```
 var rooms = [];
 getRoomsFromCSV( function (rooms) {
   for(var i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {
      console.log("i:",i);
  }
```

However, the for loop is never called and the result (room) seems to be empty.

Comment: You are re declaring `var allRoomsArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
function getRoomsFromCSV(allRoomsArray) {
  var request = require('request');
  request('http://localhost:3333/rooms.csv', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
...
      allRoomsText = allRoomsText.substr(0,allRoomsText.length-1) + ']}';
      allRoomsArray(JSON.parse(allRoomsText)); //response params to callback
  }
 })
}
```

You sent callback to retrieve response. so call that callback inside the `async` function

Comment: thx, that was it! However, rooms.length is undefined, although it has a value when I watch the rooms variable in the debugger